# How to make this simple .bat script on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: batch-file, server, backup, datastage

I try to run this simple script on Windows Serwer 2012, which works fine on Windows 7. For loop doesn't work, because parameter(%%A line of txt file) is not recognized in the statment. How I Can do this loop to works on Windows Server 2012?

```
        @Echo off 

mkdir E:\datastage_backup\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%

REM ***Nazwa serwera***
SET H = INFOSRV
REM ***Ip:Port***
SET D = 111.11.11.11:1111
REM ***Nazwa katalogu z exportem***
SET EXPORT_CMD = C:\Users\alato.EXORIGO\Desktop\export\

C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic\dsjob -server SMYK-INFOSRV -user alato -password password -domain 111.11.11.11:1111 -lprojects > %EXPORT_CMD%list.txt

@echo on

for /F %%A in (list.txt) do (
    C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic\dscmdexport %D% %H% /U=alato /P=password %%A C:\Users\alato.EXORIGO\Desktop\export\%DATE%\%%A.dsx
)
```

Comment: If you turn off `echo off` you'll probably see what is happening. I suspect you'll find your paths are wrong. Specify them.

Comment: If you ask a question, it should be a question.

Comment: you should better use `%DATE:/=-%` instead of just `%DATE%`

Answer (score 0):

For first iteration I get something like this

```
C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic\dscmdexport   /U=alato /P=rt9jTT123 %A C:\Users\alato.EXORIG
O\Desktop\export\Fri 03/11/2016\%A.dsx
```

They schould be like this:

```
    C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic\dscmdexport   /U=alato /P=rt9jTT123 VALUE_OF_VARIABLE C:\Users\alato.EXORIGO\Desktop\export\Fri 03/11/2016\VALUE_OF_VARIABLE.dsx
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You should put this information in your question (edit your question)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in SET commands unless you really want them. You should also use quotes to ensure that there are no trailing spaces. Change these lines.

```
SET "H=INFOSRV"

SET "D=111.11.11.11:1111"

SET "EXPORT_CMD=C:\Users\alato.EXORIGO\Desktop\export\"
```